# The use of stand alone prefixes of separable prefix verbs

Tags: verb, prefix

I've encountered an example of using a prefix of a separable prefix verb by itself, and I was wondering what is the right way to use such prefixes this way:

- A: Mach die Tür bitte zu!
- B: Sie ist schon **zu**.

Here it seems like a prefix stands for the entire verb "zumachen".

Is it a common way of use?

Comment: The predicate of this sentence is not anymore "Tür *zumachen*" but rather "zu sein". As elena mentioned in her answer "zu" is simply a "state" of door, like light can "be on or off". In (B) there's no relation any more to the action of closing the door. Simply "What is (state of) the door? - It's closed".

Comment: Another example:
"shut up" = "Mund zu!"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a rule, prefixes of separable verbs are words that can stand alone. You will find many prepositions among them.

---

Here, I think you misunderstood how exactly the veb "zumachen" works. "Zu" is -- among other meanings -- the German word for "closed". Unlike the English "closed", however, it is **not** the present perfect form of the word for "to close", "zumachen".

Compare:

> open -- auf
>
> closed -- zu

This might become clearer when you change your example to the opening rather than closing of a door.

> A: Mach die Tür bitte auf! -- Please open the door!
>
> B: Sie ist schon auf. -- It is already open.

Since "machen" means "make" or "do", "aufmachen" und "zumachen" literally mean "make open" and "make closed". With this somewhat wobbly translation you get the following for your example:

> Please make the door closed.
>
> It is already closed.

Doesn't work for English, I know, but this is what we do in German.

Answer (score 8):

In this special case (opened or closed doors, windows, etc.) this is rather common, though colloquial, as is *zumachen* itself. What happens here, is that *zu* has been made a [predicative adjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicative_expression) or adverb (depending on your approach to word classes) – the same may happen to *auf.* You can even find constructions like *eine zue Tür* (a closed door; pronunciation: zuë), where the *zu* is used as a regular (inflected) adjective. This is however very colloquial and not done with *auf* (at least I have never heard it).

The non-colloquial words would be:

- schließen – to close (note the difference to *verschließen* (to lock))
- geschlossen – closed (adj.) (note the difference to *verschlossen* (locked))
- öffnen – to open
- offen / geöffnet – open (adj.)

The probable origin of this usage is that *zumachen* is similar to *saubermachen* (to clean; literally: to make clean) or *kaputtmachen* (to break; literally: to make broken), where *sauber* and *kaputt* are adjectives that describe the final state that is “made”. When now (as in your example) directly after a usage of *zumachen,* somebody is required to describe the state of a door, he may fail to quickly find the correct adjective (geschlossen) and therefore settles for *zu* as an adjective due to the analogy.

Comment: In respect to "eine zue Tür" (also "eine geschlossene Tür") I think it's worth to mention that the opposite would be "eine geöffenete Tür" while "eine offene Tür" is commonly used in "Tag der offenen Tür" (=open day, open house)

Comment: @Em1: I would say that *geöffnet* and *offen* are synonymous in this context (and [the Duden agrees](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/geoeffnet)) and the latter is used outside of *Tag der offenen Tür,* e.g., in constructions like *offen stehen.* However I added *geöffnet* as an alternative to *offen.*

Comment: Could you please make it clear, that "zue Tür" is a very colloquial form. Many people complain about it even in spoken German.