# »Die Tür ist auf« vs. »Die Tür ist offen«

Tags: grammar, usage, preposition

*Auf* ist eine Präposition und kein Adjektiv. Ist es also eigentlich grammatikalisch falsch zu sagen »Die Tür ist auf«? Oder kommt es von einem Wort *aufsein*, welches ich einfach nur nicht kenne?

Dieselbe Logik betrifft ein paar umgangssprachliche Wendungen, wie z. B.:

> Die Tür ist zu.
>   Das Licht ist an/aus.

Comment: aber auf kommt doch von geöffnet und beschreib das sein und ist somit ein adjektiv, oder nicht?

Comment: @Alex: offen ist das Adjektiv. auf ist eine Präposition, oder eher eine Vorsilbe. Ich vermute, dass es davon kommt, dass man die Tür "aufmacht". Das Verb "aufmachen" gibt es, aber "aufsein", soweit ich weiß, nicht.

Comment: Not wrong. It was even [suggested in an answer](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/6569/1224) to a related question.

Comment: Was heißt "eigentlich grammatikalisch falsch"? Es gibt nicht sowas wie eigentliche Grammatik und nichteigentliche Grammatik. Es gibt nur eine Grammatik. Das, was Muttersprachler tatsächlich sagen, das ist die Grammatik. Das, was sie nicht sagen, das ist keine Grammatik. Ganz einfach. Wenn Muttersprachler "die Tür ist zu" sagen, dann ist das *per Definition* nie und niemals grammatikalisch falsch.

Comment: Die Frage in der vorliegenden Formulierung ist vollkommen unsinning. Es wird aus dem Nichts behauptet, "*auf* ist eine Präposition", und dann gleich im nächsten Satz vom Autor höchstselbst das Gegenteil bewiesen.

Comment: @RedDwight: Da stimme ich nicht ganz zu. Sogar Muttersprachler machen hin und wieder grammatikalische Fehler. In der Frage wurde überhaupt nichts "bewiesen", ich habe eine Frage gestellt.

Comment: Mal eine Frage... was willst du denn statt "Das Licht ist an" sagen?

Comment: @Emanuel: "Das Licht brennt."

Comment: "Die Alarmanlage ist an", "Die Turbine ist aus", "Der Motor ist an", "Der Herd ist an"... die Liste ist unendlich

Comment: @Emanuel: "Die Alarmanlage läuft", "Die Turbine läuft nicht", "Der Motorläuft", "Der Herdläuft", wobei das Beispiel mit der Turbine noch Differenzierung erfordert.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp.. die Alarmanlage aber auch. Denn mit "laufen" klingt es für mich so, als wäre sie am Jaulen.

Comment: Hauptsache, man rennt nicht mit zuen Augen durch ein aufes Fenster - sonst hat man bald abbe Arme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Auf* ist eine Präposition und kein Adjektiv.

Wie Emanuel schon erwähnt hat, kann ein und dasselbe Wort oft in mehreren Varianten verwendet werden. Geradezu charakteristisch für das Deutsche ist, dass sehr viele Adjektive gleichzeitig als Adverbien eingesetzt werden können – so sehr, dass einige Standardwerke den Unterschied gar nicht mehr aufführen. Es gibt auch Beispiele, wo nur die Schreibung einen Hinweis auf die Wortart enthält, wie bei *wissen/Wissen*.

In diese Kategorie gehört auch *auf*. Wenn jemand *auf der Lauer* liegt, ist *auf* eine Präposition. Aber wenn ich *die Tür aufmache*, haben wir es schon nicht mehr mit einer solchen zu tun, sondern mit einem Teil eines zusammengesetzten Verbs. Merke: *Auf* ist **nur dann** eine Präposition, wenn sie vor (»prä«) einer Lokalbezeichnung steht: *auf dem Dach, auf der Linie* etc.

Jetzt betrifft die Frage Wendungen wie

> Ich mache die Tür *auf*.
>
> Die Tür ist *auf*.

Theoretisch könnte *auf* im ersten Beispiel ein Adverb sein, vergleiche

> Ich mache die Hausaufgaben *schnell*.

Man würde aber eher davon ausgehen, dass es sich um ein zusammenzuschreibendes Verb *aufmachen* handelt – »Aufmachen! Polizei!« Passenderweise existiert auch *sich aufmachen* als eine andere Variante des Verbs.

Diese Argumentation ist für *»aufsein«*, das kanonisch so nicht angenommen wird, nur schwer möglich. Sicher, man könnte es so auffassen, und traditionellerweise werden auch »Verben« wie *dasein* als Komposita aufgefasst – zumindest habe ich den Eindruck nach der Lektüre von Grammatikwerken bekommen.

> Er wird heute abend dasein. (Rechtschreibung nach den Regeln von vor 1996)

(Ich selbst würde es getrennt schreiben, weil ich in *da* ein Lokaladverbial sehe, aber das nur am Rande.)

Dementsprechend würde ich – wieder wie Emanuel – argumentieren, dass wir es mit einem Adjektiv *auf* zu tun haben, das vorwiegend prädikativ benützt wird. Und folglich gibt es auch Gegenden in Deutschland, wo *die aufe Tür* oft gehört werden kann.

Gleichzeitig existiert analog zu *aufmachen* das Verb *öffnen*, von dem sich das vollwertige (das heißt prädikativ und attributiv verwendbar) Adjektiv *offen* ableitet – oder vielleicht war auch das Adjektiv zuerst da, das ist mir eigentlich egal. Dementsprechend hat es seit jeher selbsternannte Hochhalter der »reinen Sprache« gegeben, die von der Verwendung der Konstruktion *die Tür ist auf* abraten, oder sie gar falsch nennen, und stattdessen lieber von der *offenen Tür* sprechen, die natürlich dann auch *offen ist*.

Ob und wie diese Adjektive, um die sich die Frage dreht, attributiv gebraucht werden können, ist [Gegenstand einer anderen Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24765).

Comment: +1 für die Erwähung von prädikativen Adjektiven! (Das war mir bisher nicht so bekannt)

Answer (score 8):

Die Tür ist standardsprachlich offen, dasselbe gilt für die Augen. Standardsprachlich benutzt man »auf« in diesem Zusammenhang nur in Verbindung mit Verben, die eine entsprechende Bewegung ausdrücken (aufgehen, aufdrehen, aufplatzen usw.) – um also den Vorgang der Öffnung zu beschreiben. Wenn etwas aber mal geöffnet ist, ist es offen. Jedenfalls in der Schriftsprache.
Umgangssprachlich sind sowohl Türen als auch Augen aber durchaus auch mal auf.

Answer (score 3):

"Auf" ist nicht immer eine Präposition.

> Ich passe auf.
>   Ich habe Hausaufgaben auf.
>   Ich mache die Tür auf.

Eine Tür kann sehr wohl "auf" sein, ein Fenster "zu", Licht "aus" und Lack "ab". Alle diese Präpositionen werden adjektivisch verwendet. Bei manchen, wie zum Beispiel "zu" hat sich sogar eine andere Bedeutung entwickelt.
Warum auch nicht.

Nebenbei bemerkt:

An "Das Licht ist an" ist nichts umgangssprachlich.

Comment: "Ich passe auf" ist kein gutes Gegenbeispiel, da es vom Verb "aufpassen" kommt. Genauso "aufmachen".

Comment: @M.Herzkamp.. so what? Das Zusammen schreib en ist nur Konvention. "Ich mache mein Radio laut - laut machen", "Ich mache mein Radio an - anmachen" Das Prinzip ist das gleiche.

Comment: Und wenn man jetzt sagt "Naja, das eine  ist ein Präfix und das andere ein Adjektiv" dann warum kann ich nicht sagen "Ich mache meine Tür offen." Sollte doch gehen. Aber geht nicht, muss "auf" sein weil idiomatisch und so. Heißt aber EXAKT das gleiche.

Comment: @Emanual: Es gibt aber, soweit ich weiß, kein Verb "aufsein".

Comment: @M.Herzkamp ... https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/aufsein ... http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/auf_sein    Konvention! Was das Licht angeht... dann musst du nicht-umgangssprachliche Alternativen für ALLE Formulierungen finden. "Der Lack ist ab", "Die Alarmanlage ist an" etc.... viel Erfolg dabei.

Comment: Danke, dieser Link ist sehr hilfreich. Nimm ihn doch in deine Antwort auf :-) Ich denke allerdings nach wie vor, dass Forumlierungen wie "XYZ ist an/aus/auf/zu" tatsächlich umgangssprachlich sind und nicht in Dokumenten benutzt werden sollten.

Comment: @M.Herzkamp... ja, Antwort werde ich überarbeiten (muss jetzt los). Was umgangssprachlich angeht... in manchen Beispielen hast du Recht, bei aneren ist die "an, zu, auf, aus"-Version aber Standard.

Comment: "Alle diese Präpositionen werden als Adjektive verwendet. Warum auch nicht." - Ähhh, bitte was? "zu", beispielsweise, ist entweder eine Präposition oder ein Adjektiv, aber niemals ein "als Adjektiv verwendete Präposition".

Comment: @Em1... ich habe "Präposition" mal als die primäre, lexische Wortart verstanden. Genauso wie "schön" zwar Adjektiv und Adverb ist, aber in erster Linie mit "Adjektiv" assoziiert wird. Meintest du das?

Comment: Jap, wobei die Ableitung von Adverb zu Adjektiv nicht wirklich damit vergleichbar ist. Zugegeben, ich weiß nicht, wie die Etymologie zu "zu" aussieht. Aber ich während ich die Ableitung Adj -> Adv blind nachvollziehen kann, sehe ich keinen natürlichen Zusammenhang zw. Präposition und Adjektiv.

Comment: Vollwertige Adjektive sind sie allerdings (noch) nicht oder nur in bestimmten Varietäten der Umgangssprache: _die aufe Tür, das zue Fenster, das auße_ [sic?] _Licht, der abbe Lack_

Comment: Ah, mir geht ein Licht auf!

Comment: Anders gesagt: "Die Tür kann geöffnet werden".

Comment: @Emanuel »Ich mache die Tür klein« → »Ich mache die Tür offen« geht meines Erachtens. Schön ist zwar was anderes, aber nach Schönheit wurde nicht gefragt ;)