# Rechtschreibung adjektivierter Partikeln

Tags: colloquial, spelling, particle

Wer eine positive Antwort mit *ja* gibt, *beja**h**t* die Frage. Auch andere (unflektierte) Partikeln finden sich in flektierten Worten wieder. In [dieser Frage (und Antworten/Kommentaren darauf)](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24668/die-t%C3%BCr-ist-auf-vs-die-t%C3%BCr-ist-offen) finden sich bspw. adjektivisch verwendete *auf*, *zu*, *aus* und *ab*. Wenn diese nun umgangssprachlich nach dem Bildungsmuster *der/die/das **X** ist **y*** ⇒ *der/die/das **y**e **X*** bzw. *ein **y**er **X***, *eine **y**e **X*** und *ein **y**es **X*** gebeugt werden, wie sieht die passendste Verschriftung aus?

- ⟨**aufe** Tür⟩ vs. ⟨auffe Tür⟩ – analog *drauf*
- ⟨zues Fenster⟩ vs. ⟨**zuhes** Fenster⟩ – vgl. ⟨zunes Fenster⟩
- ⟨auses Licht⟩ vs. ⟨ausses Licht⟩ vs. ⟨**außes** Licht⟩
- ⟨aber Lack⟩ vs. ⟨**abber** Lack⟩ vs. ⟨aper Lack⟩ vs. ⟨apper Lack⟩

Ich tendiere zu folgenden (oben fett markierten) Varianten, bin mir aber unsicher:

- ⟨aufe+⟩, weil nach einem komplexen Kern (2 Vokale, Diphthong, Dehnungs-⟨h⟩) nie ein Doppelbuchstabe (Konsonant) wie ⟨ff⟩ in Rand oder Brücke auftritt
- ⟨zuhe+⟩, weil das Schwa-⟨e⟩ der Flexionssuffixe nicht direkt auf einen simplen Kern, wohl aber einen komplexen folgen darf, da V+⟨e⟩ für Umlautung und Dehnung reserviert ist; vgl. *bejahen*
- ⟨auße+⟩, weil auf einen komplexen Kern nie direkt ein Doppelbuchstabe wie ⟨ss⟩ folgt und ⟨s⟩ allein zwischen zwei Kernen immer mit /z/ korrespondiert; vgl. *außen*
- ⟨abbe+⟩, obwohl es eher /ape…/ gesprochen wird und entsprechend wohl gar keine echte Auslautverhärtung in /ap/ vorliegt, weshalb einiges für ⟨ap⟩ und dann auch ⟨appe+⟩ spricht

**Nachträge:**

- ⟨ane Lampe⟩ vs. ⟨**anne** Lampe⟩ – analog *dran*
- ⟨weges Geld⟩ vs. ⟨**wegges** Geld⟩ vs. ⟨weckes Geld⟩ vs. ⟨weches Geld⟩
- ⟨**dabeies** Kabel⟩ vs. ⟨dabeihes Kabel⟩
- ⟨ume Zeit⟩ vs. ⟨**umme** Zeit⟩
- ⟨**pfuies** Bild⟩ vs. ⟨pfuihes Bild⟩
- ⟨**durcher** Typ⟩
- ⟨**okayes** Essen⟩ vs. ⟨okaies Essen⟩ vs. ⟨okees Essen⟩ vs. ⟨okaes Essen⟩vs. ⟨okayhes Essen⟩ – vgl. ⟨okaynes Essen⟩ wie bei *zu* und bei den Farben *rosa*, *lila* und *orange*

Comment: So interessant ich die Frage finde... ist das nicht ein Fall für "opinion based"?

Comment: Das einzige deiner Beispiele was ich im realen Leben gehört habe, war das "zu(h)e Fenster". Hat jemand schonmal die anderen gehört?

Comment: @Em1: "appes Bein" habe ich schon häufiger gehört

Comment: Interessanterweise wandert bei mir bei "zu" + Endung eher ein "n" als ein "h" dazwischen; also ein "zunes Fenster".

Comment: @Em1, ich habe sie schon gehört, aber nur von meinen Kindern im Kleinkindalter. Also scheinbar per Sprachlogik quasi korrekt gebildete, dann aber im Zuge der sprachlichen Verfeinerung wieder verworfene Konstrukte.

Comment: @Chris Also wie bei _lila_, _rosa_ und manchmal _orange_? Das ist auch eine Variante, aber dort wäre die Schreibung recht eindeutig.

Comment: @Emanuel Rechtschreibung ist ja nicht völlig beliebig, aber tatsächlich könnten verschiedene Regelinterpretationen/-formulierungen zu unterschiedlichen Ergebnissen führen. Aber dass es gute Gründe für einander entgegengesetzten Theorien (≠ Meinungen) gibt, ist in der Sprache/Linguistik nicht ungewöhnlich. Schriftliche Belege für diese Wortverwendungen zu finden, dürfte abseits scherzhaften (gekünstelten) Gebrauchs schwierig werden, aber mündlich ist mir das alles (nicht nur von Kindern) schon begegnet. Man könnte es evtl. auch als Stilmittel für „einfache“ Charaktere in Prosa finden.

Comment: Das Ding ist, dass sich diese Frage nicht abschließend hier beantworten lässt. Die Tatsache, dass du selber schon Vorschläge machst, führt sehr wahrscheinlich dazu, dass diese in Antworten einfach nur diskutiert werden. Das ist aber nicht das Konzept der Seite. Was genau erwartest du dir denn hier von einer Antwort auf diese Frage?

Comment: @Emanuel Ich hoffe, dass jemand entweder aus einem Korpus die **praktisch bevorzugten Varianten** bestimmen oder aus einem graphotaktischem/orthographischem Regelsystem (nicht notwendigerweise dem amtlichen) die **theoretisch erwarteten Schreibungen** ableiten kann – oder sogar beides. Der naive Wörterbuchansatz dürfte fehlschlagen.

Comment: Gut, das kann ich nachvollziehen.

Comment: Ich versteh den Zusammenhang zwischen _bejahen_ und den anderen Beispielen nicht. _Ja_ und _Nein_ sind laut Duden Partikel, aber _ab_, _zu_, _aus_ und _auf_ sind doch Adverben und keine Partikel, oder?

Comment: Ich verbessere das nicht selber, weil ich mir nicht ganz sicher bin, ob es vielleicht verschiedene richtige Varianten gibt, aber ich glaube, das *n* ganz am Ende der Überschrift ist zu viel.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... crissov meint "Partikel" im grammatischen Sinn. Das ist zur Verwirrung aller "die Partikel" (nicht der) und im Plural "die Partikeln". Warum das jetzt "die" sein muss und nicht "das" sein kann... keine Ahnung. Jedenfalls ist das "n" richtig, da Teil des Plural. Gemeint sind mit Partikeln je nach Definition ALLE nicht flektierbaren Wörter oder nicht flektierbare Wörter ausser Adverben, Präpositionen und  Konjunktionen.

Comment: @Emanuel, wieder was gelernt, Danke! https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Partikel#Substantiv.2C_f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wie du richtig erwähnst, sind die erfragten Konstruktionen alle umgangssprachlich, denn standardsprachlich können die Adjektive *an, dran, weg, auf, zu* etc. nur prädikativ, nicht aber attributiv, verwendet werden. Dementsprechend gibt es auch – ganz im Gegenteil zu *verneinen* und *bejahen* – keine standardsprachlich akzeptierten Schreibungen für die flektierten, attributiv verwendeten Varianten.

Erschwerend kommt hinzu, dass die Konstruktion nicht überall im deutschen Sprachraum verwendet wird. Ein Bayer würde auf eine *aufe Tür* wahrscheinlich mit »Saubreiß« antworten.

Trotzdem ist der Wunsch nach einer Standardschreibung nicht verkehrt: In Comics, wörtlich wiedergegebener Umgangssprache oder Chats könnten die Formen durchaus auftreten. Gleichzeitig könnten gleiche Formen von verschiedenen Sprechern auch durchaus unterschiedlich ausgesprochen werden: Siehe die Beispiele *der Draht ist ab* (bleibt die Auslautverhärtung bestehen oder nicht?) und alles, was ein zu *ch* verschliffenes *g* enthält (wird das *g* durch Flexion zurückgewonnen?).

Aus all dem zusammengenommen kann nur gefolgert werden, dass die Schreibung frei ist, aber sowohl die Eigenheiten des Sprechers als auch die Lesbarkeit berücksichtigen sollte. Deine ausgesuchten Beispiele würde ich wahrscheinlich auch bevorzugen, mit folgenden Einschränkungen:

- **außes** – wenn das *auße* Licht zum Dativ wird, oder von einem entsprechenden Motor gesprochen wird, muss man abwägen, ob *außer* und *außen* falsch verstanden werden können, und gegebenenfalls auf *aus-er* oder ähnliche Behelfsformen ausweichen.
- **abber** – ist nur gültig, wenn der mittlere Konsonant auch ein Lenis ist (in Hessen durchaus möglich!). Ich habe durchaus auch Aussprachen gehört, die ich mit *apper* wiedergeben würde.
- **wegges** – entsprechend dem *abben*. Nur, wenn das *gg* auch als [g] gelesen wird. Wird es »preußisch«, also als [ç] ausgesprochen, muss man *weches* schreiben. *Weges* verbietet sich, weil das *e* lang würde.

Seien wir froh, dass die deutsche Rechtschreibung so regelmäßig ist, dass wir für diese Art Ausdrücke Schreibungen finden können, die alle intuitiv richtig lesen würden. Man stelle sich Gleiches auf Englisch vor; das ist viel schwieriger.

Answer (score 1):

> Apper Draht ist weches Geld.

Im Ernst: Es spielt praktisch keine Rolle, denn es ist (selten) gesprochenes Deutsch und daher gibt es keine Regel und wichtiger noch: Kaum ein Leser hat das schon mal *geschrieben* gesehen, daher ist *keine* Schreibweise eine Hilfe. Solche Formulierungen werden immer dazu führen, dass der Leser im Zweifel mehrmals darauf gucken muss.

Sicher hilfreich ist, wenn die Schreibweise etwas phonetisch Ähnliches nahelegt. Das heißt für mich (eher breites Westfälisch/Ruhrgebietsdeutsch):

- zuhes (*zues* ist für mich *züs*)
- auffe
- ausses
- appes

Aber ich kann mir sehr gut vorstellen, dass Leute andernorts *ab-er* Draht sagen würden.

Kleiner Nachtrag:
Mir fällt gerade auf, dass ich die logisch gleichwertigen und nicht wesentlich schlimmer klingenden Konstruktionen *annes* ("die anne Lampe" für "die eingeschaltete Lampe") oder *drannes* ("dranner Draht ist da-es Geld"? ;)) noch nie gehört habe.

Comment: "Anne Lampe/annes Licht" hab ich schon öfter im Kontext von Fahrradfahren/nachts/Polizei benutzt.

Comment: Oh, und ein sehr gängiges Beispiel ist "drauf"... "der draufe Idiot", "Nur draufe Leute da" etc

Comment: @Emanuel: Sehr regional anscheinend. Was bedeutet _drauf_ in diesem Fall denn? Kann man auch etwas sagen wie _Alle Leute waren drauf_ (und damit nicht einfach meinen, daß sie auf dem Foto, auf der Bühne o.ä. waren)? _Gut/schlecht drauf sein_ kenne ich.

Comment: @chirlu drauf wie "auf" Drogen (ggf. Alkohol), das ist zumindest die mir geläufige bedeutung, also jemand der dermaßen nicht auf der Höhe ist, dass Drogenkonsum wahrscheinlich erscheint